# Transfer data from large multidimensional array to smaller multidimensional array - is it worth?

Tags: php, quickbooks

Is it worth to create smaller multidimensional array (3 col x Z rows) from bigger one (67 col x Z rows) for faster data processing? Data are imported from Quickbooks.

Process will looks like:

- set big array
- get QB data and store into a big array
- set small array
- store related QB data from a big array to a small array
- unset big array
- manipulate data based on QB data from a small array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first question you ask yourself should be:

- *Are you actually running into performance problems?*

If so, then you need to *benchmark your application* to determine if creating those smaller arrays is going to improve performance.

If it is, and you're having performance problems, then it's worth it.

If you're not having performance problems yet... then you shouldn't even be thinking about doing this yet. Don't try to optimize without benchmarking and knowing for sure if this is actually a problem.

All that said... given that PHP arrays are basically big hashmaps, I find it unlikely that breaking it into a bunch of smaller arrays is going to make any performance difference what-so-ever.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. As you said now I don't see any differences between two versions of that code (small vs big array) running simple benchmark (execution microtime). But always is better to ask more experienced devs before I will run into some further issues :)